# What's Wuala's policy on hotlinking?

Tags: links, online-storage, file-sharing

Does Wuala allow me to link to my file from my website?

If so, are there any limits on the bandwidth?

Example:

http://wuala.com/John/Wuala%20Pressmaterial/Logos/EPS/ (directory listing)

Direct link to a file:

http://content.wuala.com/contents/John/Wuala%20Pressmaterial/Logos/EPS/wuala_logo-SIMPLE.eps?dl=1

(not my files, just an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuala) states the following:

> share files with unregistered users, through a keyed hyperlink

As long as you use the 'keyed hyperlink', you should be ok.

Users on Wuala's support [forum back this up](https://forum.wuala.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=569&p=2380&hilit=hotlink#p2380):

> Das ist schon ok. Wenn ein File zu oft abgefragt wird, gibt es aber
> eine Bandbreitenbeschränkung im Webinterface.

Translated: "It's ok. When a file is retreived too many times, there is a bandwith limit in the Webinterface."

Answer (score 2):

Coming directly from the [FAQ](http://wuala.com/en/support/faq), yes, you are able to - using a [secret link](http://www.wuala.com/en/support/faq/c/2#id000223).

`Q: Can I share folders with contacts who do not use Wuala?`

`A: Yes, of course. Simply create a secret link and send it to your contact.`